# tcpdump takes O(n²) time to parse filter

Tags: tcpdump

I run `tcpdump` with a filter like:

```
 not (
     (host 1.165.155.169 and port 4444)
  or (host 1.168.68.116 and port 4444)
  or (host 1.173.192.253 and port 4444)
  or (host 1.174.97.43 and port 4444)
  :
  or (host 161.138.104.1 and port 58339)
)
```

My problem is that `tcpdump` takes O(n²) time when starting, and I have several 100s of lines. When it is started, it works fine. It seems it is only the initialization that is O(n²) - not the normal processing.

[image: Lines in filter vs runtime]
Is there a way I can tell `tcpdump` to optimize initialization to O(n) or at least O(n log n)?

I have a table of <ip,port>.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the ideas. So far all of them give O(n²).

There is no reason to wait for me to test your idea. Here is a script to test with:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                              

# Make some network noise                                                                
(sudo nice nice ping -f localhost >/dev/null) &
noisepid=$!

filter() {
    # $1 = How many entries?                                                             
    perl -e '                                                                            
        $pre = "not (";                                                                  
        $post = ")";                                                                     
        $join = " and ";                                                                 
        sub hostport {                                                                   
          $host = sprintf "%d.%d.%d.%d", rand()*255,rand()*255,rand()*255,rand()*255;    
          $port = sprintf "%d", rand()*65535;                                            
          return "(host $host and port $port)";                                          
        }                                                                                
        print $pre, join($join,map { hostport() } 1..shift), $post;                      
    ' $1
}
export -f filter

seq 400 | parallel --joblog my.log 'sudo tcpdump -ni any "`filter {}`"|read a'
kill -9 $noisepid
# field - https://codeberg.org/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/field                  
# plotpipe - https://codeberg.org/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/plotpipe            
field 14,4 < my.log | sort -n | plotpipe
```

`tcpdump -F file` is faster, but still O(n²).

EDIT2:

Graphs re-done on other server (i.e. the numbers cannot be compared with previous graph) with `tcpdump` and `tcpdump -O`

[image: with or without -O]

`-O` clearly makes it worse.

Comment: I suspect (haven't checked the source code) that what `tcpdump` does here is compile your filter into a reduced-as-possible form. What you could try is of course could be that optimizer: Say instead of "not ( ⋃ᵢ(host Hᵢ and port Pᵢ))"  do something like "not ( ⋃ᵢ (Port Pᵢ and (⋃ᵣ host Hᵢᵣ)))", if there's many hosts for one port. Generally, however, this is a satisfiability problem… and thus rather hard computationally.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For testing I simply removed the port. It is faster, but still takes O(n²) to initialize.

Comment: Do you launch tcpdump **-n** ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes. The problem is clearly not DNS: The CPU is running at 100% during initialization.

Comment: Applying De Morgan’s laws might help: instead of “not ((h1 and p1) or (h2 and p2) …)”, “not (h1 and p1) and not (h2 and p2) …”

Comment: @StephenKitt This also gives O(n²).

Comment: @OleTange things also don't get better with `-O`? That would disable the optimization done in `pcap_compile` that I suspected in my first comment. If that changes things, you can use `sudo perf record -ag --symbols=pcap_compile tcpdump …` to track where the pcap library spends its time (show the results using `perf report`; gets more useful with debugging symbols for libpcap)

Comment: (I don't know about the actual issue, but at least the graph looks worse than O(n^2) to me. The y-value at x=150 is about 3, but at x=300, it's already > 40, way more than a four-fold increase you'd expect for a quadratic relation.)

Comment: (@ilkkachu Fair point. My n² was purely eyeballing it - it was clearly not O(n log n) )

Comment: @MarcusMüller See new graph: -O did not help. perf gives me: "+   23.42%    23.42%  tcpdump          libpcap.so.1.10.1                     [.] 00000000000262bc" (The  --symbols=pcap_compile did not work).

Comment: @OleTange Interesting! So, it *is* within libpcap, but not the rule optimization. Sadly, we only get a position, not a function name. I'd *guess* that gets better when you do get debug symbols to libpcap, but I can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. I have filed https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/1255

Post an answer if you find a work-around.

Answer (score -2):

You can work with specific IPs and ports.

Example

```
sudo tcpdump -n src 000.00.0.255 and tcp port 80 #You only see a packet
```

you should change the ip and port

```
sudo tcpdump -n src 000.00.0.255 and tcp port 80 > myipandport.txt #If you need to save the information
```

Comment: Did you miss the 'not' in the filter? I am not looking for packets from these servers. I am looking for all *other* packets.